# Call a different version of jQuery for a specific element

Tags: jquery

I am on jQuery 3.2

I need to use only for a specific HTML block jQuery 1.7

Is there a way in jQuery to specify which jQuery version to call for a specific HTML element.

Or if I have to user the noconflict, could anyone explain in the details how it works? I have never understood it!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

See this jQuery forum posting about how to put multiple versions of jQuery on the same page: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page and also this previous SO post: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).

I must say that this seems like a total hack that is quite inefficient.  You should fix one block of code to use the same jQuery version as the other block and only load one version of jQuery.

FYI, these two posts came right up when I Googled for "multiple versions of jquery loaded" and there are lots of other resources about this topic in that same search.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think you must change $ shortform of jquery comments for one of them.

ex :

$ for Jquery 1.4
$$ for Jquery 1.6